# Record that needs to be updated has a field name including & for which TOAD prompts to enter a variable

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, updates, toad

I have a requirement where i need to amend the 1500 records.
There are  some fields in random ,of the where clause has an & as mentioned below:

```
    update abc where col1='AL_ATRADE_P&L_RP'
```

I just wanted to execute the 1500 udpate queries as a script and TOAD prompts me for the variable to be entered.
If i just press enter the udpate query is taken as below:

```
    update abc where col1='AL_ATRADE_P'
```

But in actual my record has a collumn with name 'AL_ATRADE_P&L_RP'

Any suggestion to get rid of this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066558/toad-thinks-string-as-bind-variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in TOAD right click on the SQL window, and you should see an option that is ticked "Prompt for substitution variables". Un-tick this, and TOAD Will not try to replace the ampersand any more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Dazzal answer. The same can be done in sqlplus by just using the below: SET DEFINE OFF; This is same as setting the prompt for substitution variables to none in TOAD. Just thought of sharing this with you all